# convert base64 url to binary in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, byte

How can I easily convert a base64 URL encoded string into a bytes string in plain javascript?

For instance, `myEncodeFunction("BOEFEA")` should render `"00000100111000010000010100010000"`.

I got it from [there](https://cryptii.com/base64-to-hex).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function base642Binary(str) {
    return atob(str).split('').map(c => {
        return c.charCodeAt(0).toString(2).padStart(8, '0');
    }).join(' ');
}
var binary = base642Binary('BOEFEA');
```